# How to convert the default file path in java?

Tags: java, file

I am trying to get File path from a file and save the file path in a file and call it back, to send as an attachment in a mail.

```
File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
String source = file.getAbsolutePath();
println(source);
```

But the output will be something like this

```
C:\Documents and Settings\TheFile.txt
```

But I am looking for a way to get the source as

```
C:\\Documents and Settings\\TheFile.txt
```

Is there any method to convert? Thanks for help!

Comment: Both look same to me. If you want double back slash, you can use `stirng.replace("\\","\\\\");`

Comment: The path is correct. Perhaps you want to copy and paste it into a Java string - then you need to quote the slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier way should be write a function which does

```
String getPath(){
File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
String source = file.getAbsolutePath();
source .replace("\\","\\\\"); 
return source;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
File f = [your file]
String filename = f.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
```

Write the 'filename' back to the file and you'll have single slashes replaced with double slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
String source = file.getAbsolutePath();
String sourceConverted = source.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
```